# Port number for a svn:// style URL

Tags: svn

I am running svnserve with a different port number, by using the listen-port option. How do I access such a repository?

I tried `svn ls svn://<server name>:<new port number/<respository name>`. It does not work. How should I use instead?

Comment: Can you show the full svn URL you are trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
svn://{somednsname}:portnumber
```

For example:

```
svn://somedomainname.com:8443/svn/myprojectroot/trunk
```

Comment: I tried svn://somedomainname.com:8443, but I get connection refused error.

Comment: I'll assume you actually didn't try "somedomainname.com" on port 8443 but your actual server... You may try actually just doing a telnet on that port to the server.  If you get blocked there or it fails to connect then you could use wireshark to see if you are getting a [syn,ack] response from the server.  If you are not then either the svn server is not listening on that port or you are getting blocked by a firewall.  If you see a [rst,ack] in the wireshark log then that is an indication that you are being explicitly denied access...